# How to write Rudin's symbol for absolute continuity of measures?

Tags: math-mode, symbols

In Rudin's Real and Complex Analysis, there is a symbol for stating measure `$\lambda$` is absolutely continuous with respect to measure `$\mu$`. The symbol is like `$\lambda\ll\mu$`, but not exactly.

Answer (score 9):

If one doesn't want to load the whole lot of **mathabx**, that changes the shape of many symbols, it's possible to load only the one needed, see [Importing a single symbol font from a different font](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14386/importing-a-single-symbol-from-a-different-font).

The definition would be

```
\DeclareMathSymbol{\Lt}{3}{matha}{"CE}
```

using the **unicode-math** name or, if the alternative way by **pisymbol** is preferred,

```
\newcommand{\Lt}{\Pimathsymbol[\mathrel]{matha}{"CE}}
```

The complete series of declarations in the preamble should be

```
\DeclareFontFamily{U}{matha}{\hyphenchar\font45}
\DeclareFontShape{U}{matha}{m}{n}{
  <-6> matha5 <6-7> matha6 <7-8> matha7
  <8-9> matha8 <9-10> matha9
  <10-12> matha10 <12-> matha12
  }{}
% \DeclareFontShape{U}{matha}{m}{n}{
%   <5> <6> <7> <8> <9> <10> gen * matha
%   <10.95> matha10 <12> <14.4> <17.28>
%   <20.74> <24.88> matha12
%   }{}

\DeclareSymbolFont{matha}{U}{matha}{m}{n}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\Lt}{3}{matha}{"CE}
```

If your TeX distribution is fairly recent you can leave out the commented lines (starting with `%`); otherwise, uncomment them and delete the similar ones above. It has to do with the presence of the Type1 (scalable) versions of the mathabx fonts.

With the alternative method that doesn't reserve a math alphabet, the code to write in the preamble is

```
\usepackage{pifont}
\DeclareFontFamily{U}{matha}{\hyphenchar\font45}
\DeclareFontShape{U}{matha}{m}{n}{
  <-6> matha5 <6-7> matha6 <7-8> matha7
  <8-9> matha8 <9-10> matha9
  <10-12> matha10 <12-> matha12
  }{}
\makeatletter
\newcommand\Pimathsymbol[3][\mathord]{%
  #1{\@Pimathsymbol{#2}{#3}}}
\def\@Pimathsymbol#1#2{\mathchoice
  {\@Pim@thsymbol{#1}{#2}\tf@size}
  {\@Pim@thsymbol{#1}{#2}\tf@size}
  {\@Pim@thsymbol{#1}{#2}\sf@size}
  {\@Pim@thsymbol{#1}{#2}\ssf@size}}
\def\@Pim@thsymbol#1#2#3{%
  \mbox{\fontsize{#3}{#3}\Pisymbol{#1}{#2}}}
\makeatother
\newcommand{\Lt}{\Pimathsymbol[\mathrel]{matha}{"CE}}
```

For the `\DeclareFontShape` command it's the same as before.

Comment: thank you for your answer. I do want to be able to import the symbols needed only. I am having some trouble here to do that. I tried with \DeclareFontFamily{U}{matha}{\hyphenchar\font45} \DeclareFontShape{U}{matha}{m}{n}{ <5> <6> <7> <8> <9> <10> gen * matha <10.95> matha10 <12> <14.4> <17.28> <20.74> <24.88> matha12 }{} \DeclareMathSymbol{\Lt}{3}{matha}{"CE} , but I am getting an error Symbol font matha' is not defined.`

Comment: @Qiang Li: you missed the `\DeclareSymbolFont{matha}{U}{matha}{m}{n}` line. I've added the complete code.

Comment: +1 and thank you. Now it is working! So I assume the first approach is to use the alias in the unicode-math. How to use the symbol directly, as Caramdir said in his/her post?

Answer (score 5):

Have a look at [“How to look up a math symbol?”](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14/how-to-look-up-a-math-symbol) for ideas how you can easily find a particular symbol.

The symbols list has `\lll` from the `mathabx` package (note that you need to load `mathabx` after `amsmath`, because `amsmath` defines `\lll` as ⋘.

Unicode defines the symbols as `⪡ U+2AA1 DOUBLE NESTED LESS-THAN`. If you use [`unicode-math`](http://ctan.org/pkg/unicode-math), you can use the symbol directly or use the alias `\Lt`.

Comment: @egreg: thank you for your answer. I do want to be able to import the symbols needed only. I am having some trouble here to do that. I tried with `\DeclareFontFamily{U}{matha}{\hyphenchar\font45}
\DeclareFontShape{U}{matha}{m}{n}{
      <5> <6> <7> <8> <9> <10> gen * matha
      <10.95> matha10 <12> <14.4> <17.28> <20.74> <24.88> matha12
      }{}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\Lt}{3}{matha}{"CE}
`, but I am getting an error `Symbol font `matha' is not defined.`

Comment: @Qiang: Your comment is on the wrong answer.