# negation of \pitchfork

Tags: symbols

Is there a symbol for "non-transversality" (or how to create it)? I am thinking about something similar to the negation of the symbol `\pitchfork`. I did not find anything like this in the list of available symbols.

Comment: Have you tried `\not\pitchfork`? BTW, [Welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx).

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) Usually, we don't put a greeting or a "thank you" in our posts. While this might seem strange at first, it is not a sign of lack of politeness, but rather part of our trying to keep everything very concise. Upvoting is the preferred way here to say "thank you" to users who helped you.

Comment: @PeterGrill  ok, I didn't know the \not command, it seems very useful

Answer (score 4):

If you're interested in extracting *only* the symbol you're after from [`MnSymbol`](http://ctan.org/pkg/mnsymbol), then you can follow the procedure listed in [Interior product (contraction) symbol](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/38917/5764).

Here is an MWE that defines `\nontrans` as a binary relation:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}% http://ctan.org/pkg/amsmath
\usepackage{fonttable}% http://ctan.org/pkg/fonttable
\DeclareFontFamily{U}{MnSymbolB}{}
\DeclareSymbolFont{MnSyB}{U}{MnSymbolB}{m}{n}
\DeclareFontShape{U}{MnSymbolB}{m}{n}{
    <-6>  MnSymbolB5
   <6-7>  MnSymbolB6
   <7-8>  MnSymbolB7
   <8-9>  MnSymbolB8
   <9-10> MnSymbolB9
  <10-12> MnSymbolB10
  <12->   MnSymbolB12}{}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\nontrans}{\mathbin}{MnSyB}{'211}% Symbol 211
\begin{document}

$A\nontrans B$

\end{document}
```

In fact, `\nontrans` is symbol `'211` (octal, or decimal `137`) from `MnSymbolB`. Here's the font table if you're interested in extracting a different symbol:

[image]

The above font table was created via the [`fonttable` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/fonttable) and adding

```
\xfonttable{U}{MnSymbolB}{m}{n}% MnSymbolB font table
```

to the above MWE.

Comment: Well done! I would just add that for consistency it is probably good to use the symbol for `\pitchfork` from `MnSymbol` as well (it is in `MnSymbolA` font I believe).

Answer (score 3):

The  MnSymbol Pitchforks provides `\nuppitchfork` found in [The Comprehensive LATEX Symbol List](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/info/symbols/comprehensive/symbols-a4.pdf) by Scott Pakin on page 47.

[image: example]

EDIT:

To create a similar effect, try the following though to my knowledge it is not the most appropriate Latex way of negating a Math Symbol:

```
 \documentclass[letterpaper]{article}
 \usepackage{mathabx}
 \begin{document}
 \makebox[1em]{$\pitchfork$}\hspace{-1em}\makebox[1em]{/}
 \end{document}
```

Which produces:
[image: test]

Comment: beware the side effects of `mathabx`; it changes the shape of *many* symbols.  if just one or two symbols are needed, there is a "recipe" for accomplishing that in an answer to [this question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/19981).

Comment: I suppose so, my suggestion is just a sample with a `\pitchfork` without negation.

Comment: but a `\pitchfork` does require a package that provides the symbol.  the package shown in your example is `mathabx`.  (this symbol is also provided by `\usepackage{amssymb}`, which conflicts with none of the "standard" computer modern symbols.  there may be others that don't have such a wide-reaching scope, but i haven't checked.)

Comment: `MnSymbol` is a package that provides really a lot of symbols, but changes the appearance of a lot of symbols. I would really need some option passed to that package, so that I can write e.g. `\Mn{\pitchfork}` to get the one from `MnSymbol` package and without `\Mn` to get the symbols as usual.

Answer (score 1):

I guess that the following code gives pretty good results, that are consinstent while scaling. (We made an `\overline` over something that has a width of the symbol and height of a single `.`.)

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{amssymb}
\def\npitchfork{\mathrel{\overline{\vphantom{.}\smash{\pitchfork}}}}

\begin{document}

\[
A \npitchfork B_{{X\npitchfork Y}_{M\npitchfork N}}
\]

\end{document}
```