# Is there a (fork) symbol for probabilistic causality? Logic

Tags: symbols, logic

I found pitchforks, but none that is similar to these explaines in Salmon 1989

[image]

[image]

Thanks!!

Comment: Maybe `$\supset\mkern-15mu-_u$`

Comment: Doesn't [this answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/43702/101651) help you?

Comment: Hi CarlaTex, thanks! I saw this list, but the symbols are a bit different. Thanks again.

Comment: Hi Steven, it did! thanks a lot! Maybe you want to add this as an answer and provide the context? thanks a lot!

Comment: Just for fun: `\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{marvosym}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}
\rotatebox{90}{\Neptune}
\end{document}` :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Since it should be a connective, the type is `\mathbin`; then we can use TeX's rules for relations:

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand{\fork}{%
  \mathbin{%
    \supset
    \mathrel{\mkern-9mu}%
    \mathrel{-}%
  }%
}

\begin{document}

The connective for the fork is $\fork$
and we can write $a\fork b$ or also
$a\fork_u b$.

\end{document}
```

Choose the kerning based on your liking.

[image]

Answer (score 6):

At its simplest, I propose a simple overlap of a `\supset` and a `-`, with a kern to effect the overlap.  However, A Rmano notes, this may not have the proper spacing relative to adjacent material.  Thus, if one wishes a general symbol, that works across math styles, I have provided here `\fork`.

EDITED for `\mathbin` instead of `\mathrel`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{scalerel}
\newcommand\fork{\mathbin{\ThisStyle{{\supset}\kern-\dimexpr.5\LMex+3pt\relax{-}}}}
\begin{document}

$\supset\mkern-15mu-_\mathrm{u}$

$\fork_\mathrm{u}$
$\scriptstyle \fork_\mathrm{u}$
$\scriptscriptstyle \fork_\mathrm{u}$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Hmmm... I think that the `_mathrm{u}` should go *into* the `mathrel` --- otherwise it's strange. Try `$A fork_\mathrm{u} B$` versus `$A \mathrel{\supset\mkern-15mu-_\mathrm{u}} B$`... maybe an optional argument?

Comment: @Rmano The initial version may indeed have the wrong spacing, and I showed it to convey the gist of the approach.  For regular use, I certainly endorse the use of `\fork` as the preferred embodiment.

Comment: Yes... but `$A\fork_u B$` has still the wrong spacing, because the `_u` should go *into* the `mathbin`, no? Or am I wrong? (can't check now...)

Comment: @Rmano I don't know enough about the contextual meaning of the symbol and its usage to know the answer to your question.  I would just note that egreg, who would know the answers to these questions, did not place the subscript inside the `\mathbin`.

Answer (score 5):

`Mnsymbol` and `Mdsymbol` have `\rightpitchfork` glyphs (and indeed quite a few other `pitchforks`). Here is a way to use it, along with `\leftpitchfork`, without loading Mnsymbol. In addition , I defined  an extensible version  `\xleftfork`. They have bold versions.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern, mathtools}

\DeclareFontFamily{U}  {MnSymbolA}{}
\DeclareSymbolFont{MnSyA}         {U}  {MnSymbolA}{m}{n}
\SetSymbolFont{MnSyA}       {bold}{U}  {MnSymbolA}{b}{n}
\DeclareFontShape{U}{MnSymbolA}{m}{n}{
<-6>  MnSymbolA5
<6-7>  MnSymbolA6
<7-8>  MnSymbolA7
<8-9>  MnSymbolA8
<9-10> MnSymbolA9
<10-12> MnSymbolA10
<12->   MnSymbolA12}{}
\DeclareFontShape{U}{MnSymbolA}{b}{n}{
<-6>  MnSymbolA-Bold5
<6-7>  MnSymbolA-Bold6
<7-8>  MnSymbolA-Bold7
<8-9>  MnSymbolA-Bold8
<9-10> MnSymbolA-Bold9
<10-12> MnSymbolA-Bold10
<12->   MnSymbolA-Bold12}{}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\xleftfork}[2][]{%
\ext@arrow 0079\xleftforkfill@{#1}{#2}%
}
\newcommand{\xleftforkfill@}{%
\arrowfill@\Mnrelbar\Mnrelbar{\mathrel{\leftpitchfork}}
}
\newcommand{\xrightfork}[2][]{%
\ext@arrow 0097\xrightforkfill@{#1}{#2}%
}

\DeclareMathSymbol{\rightpitchfork}{\mathrel}{MnSyA}{"88}%
\DeclareMathSymbol{\leftpitchfork}{\mathrel}{MnSyA}{"8A}%
\DeclareMathSymbol{\Mnrelbar}{\mathrel}{MnSyA}{"D0}%

\begin{document}

$ A \rightpitchfork B\enspace B \leftpitchfork A$
\bigskip

\boldmath      $ A \rightpitchfork B\enspace B \leftpitchfork A$
\bigskip

$C \xleftfork{\text{an extensible pitchfork}}D$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I don't think the extensible pitchfork is useful but it looks nice :) +1

Comment: It was asked for not long ago  on this site. I tried for fun to obtain an extensible pitchfork with a \rightpitchfork on the left, but didn't succeed (missing $ was the error message…)

Answer (score 4):

In Unicode there is the similar symbol `\nisd`.  However, it is a relation rather than a binary operator.  It is not available in all fonts but XITS has it.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmathfont{XITS Math}
\begin{document}
$a \nisd b$
\end{document}
```

[image]